# Functionality for a Pokemon fight in R: how to loop over attacks until one faints?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am trying to create the functionality for a fight between Mewtwo and Rayquaza in R for a programming project. I am using "The Complete Pokemon Dataset" from Kaggle. I have successfully coded "round 1", but my problem is that when i attempt to loop over it until one Pokemon faints it just starts over. I want it to "remember" the HP of the Pokemon after it has suffered an attack. My code looks like this:

```
round1 <- function(){
  M<- sample(c("Psystrike", "Aura Sphere", "Ice Punch",
               "Solar Beam"))
  R <- sample(c("Outrage", "Dragon Ascent", "Crunch",
                "Brutal Swing"))
  
  for (i in c("Ready", "Set", "Go!")){
    
    print(i)
    Sys.sleep(1.2)
    
  } 
  
  if (speedM>speedR && M == "Ice Punch"){
    print(Rextremedamage(75))
    print("Ice Punch is hyper effective!")
  }
    
  if (speedM>speedR && M== "Psystrike"){
    print(Rdamage(100))
    print("Psystrike has normal efficiency.")
    }
  if (speedM>speedR && M== "Aura Sphere"){
    print(Rlowdamage(80))
    print("Aura Sphere is not very effective...")
  }
  if (speedM>speedR && M== "Solar Beam"){
    print(Rlowdamage(100))
    print("Solar Beam is not very effective...")
  }
  
  
    Sys.sleep(1.4)
  
  
  for (a in c("Rayquaza is angry...", "Go!")){
    
    print(a)
    Sys.sleep(1.2)
    
  }
  
  if (hpRayquaza >0 && R == "Outrage"){
    print(Mdamage(120))
    print("Outrage has normal efficiency.")
  }
  if (hpRayquaza >0 && R == "Dragon Ascent"){
    print(Mdamage(120))
    print("Dragon Ascent has normal efficiency.")
  }
  if (hpRayquaza >0 && R == "Crunch"){
    print(Mhighdamage(80))
    print("Crunch is super effective!")
  }
  if (hpRayquaza >0 && R == "Brutal Swing"){
    print(Mhighdamage(60))
    print("Brutal swing is super effective!")
  }
    
}
```

Fyi, the "damage" functions are coded like this:

```
Mhighdamage <- function(x){
  pain=hpMewTwo-x/1.8
  return(pain)
}
```

...where "hpMewTwo" is the HP for mewtwo given in the dataset(106). My output looks like this:

```
> round1()
[1] "Ready"
[1] "Set"
[1] "Go!"
        hp
1 87.97872
[1] "Aura Sphere is not very effective..."
[1] "Rayquaza is angry..."
[1] "Go!"
        hp
1 61.55556
[1] "Crunch is super effective!"
```

I attempted to put round 1 in a while loop, but it just kept on running through the code and then starting from the top with full HP forever. Does anyone have a clue on how i can run a loop that "remembers" the HP and runs until one hits zero?

Comment: FYI, you probably want to replace all your `print` calls by `message`.

Comment: from what I am able to grasp from your code I would suggest running something like `assign(hpMewTwo, hpMewTwo-x/1.8)` in your damage function and then `return(hpMewTwo)`. That way the next time hpMewTwo gets called in the damage function it will remember the assigned value.

Comment: Thanks! Should I change both ```print``` calls or just the one stating the effectiveness?

Comment: Thank you Wietse! I will try it out. I am fairly new to R programming so these pieces of advice really helps a lot.

Comment: @WietsedeVries I think we're on to something here, but when i run ```remhp <- function(x){
  au=hpRayquaza-x/4.7
  assign(hpRayquaza, hpRayquaza-x/4.7)
  
  return(hpRayquaza)
}
remhp(50) ``` I get the error ```Error in assign(hpRayquaza, hpRayquaza - x/4.7) : invalid first argument```. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Yea, after running the code myself I realized I fell into some pitfalls. This is how I have written the function now: `Mhighdamage <- function(x) {
  assign("hpMewTwo", hpMewTwo-x/1.8, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`. No need for a return statement really, unless you want to put a message there to print. First thing I changed is putting the first variable within quotes, which is required. The second thing I changed is assigning the variable to the global environment, if not specified the assigning will only take place within the function.

Comment: @WietsedeVries this worked! However, I now faced a different problem. Each time I run the function it now remembers the last time I ran it, so the HP values just keeps on declining. Is there a way to kind of "reset" the HP for every time i run the function? So that a new game begins for each time I mean.

Comment: So essentially what you have is you run 1 game (1 function call), in this game you run multiple rounds in a while statement until the HP of either pokemon hits 0, right? If so than I would write a small code at the beginning of your function (note: outside of the while statement) that initializes the hp of both pokemon, that way when the code hits reaches your while statement it takes the full hp of both pokemon

Comment: Tag me when you finish the project, I'd like to see it

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could do this using while.
In general if you want to make an ABM i would suggest to you to use some sort of agent struct ( like a setClass(Class="Pokemon") or simply a list or vecor)
)of type pokemon.The pokemon can have different fields (id, name, lvl, hp, attacks, type)  then bulid a fight function that is general for all agents (pokemon) and takes inputs `poke1` , `poke2` instead of hpMewtown...
Then you can run a multiple fights by using something like listapply or even build a tournament by sampling pokemons to duos.
tipp Try to keep Functions as general and reusable as possible.

```
## Damage system
highdamage <- function(x){
  dmg=-x/0.8
  return(dmg)
}

extremedamage <- function(x){
  dmg=-x/0.5
  return(dmg)
}

lowdamage<- function(x){
  dmg=-x/2
  return(dmg)
}


damage<- function(x){
  dmg=-x/1
  return(dmg)
}
####

round1 <- function(hpRayquaza,hpMewtwo){

# START
  for (i in c("Ready", "Set", "Go!")){
    print(i)
    Sys.sleep(1)
  } 
# ALIVE
  while (hpRayquaza>0 && hpMewtwo>0){
# WHO ATTACKS FASTER
    speedM<-rnorm(1,mean = speedM_v,3)
    speedR<-rnorm(1,mean = speedR_v,3)
    M<- sample(c("Psystrike", "Aura Sphere", "Ice Punch",
                 "Solar Beam"),1)
    R <- sample(c("Outrage", "Dragon Ascent", "Crunch",
                  "Brutal Swing"),1)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    if(speedM > speedR ){  
      for(a in c("Mewtwo attacks...", "Go!")){
        print(a)
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }
      if(M == "Ice Punch"){
        dmg<-extremedamage(75)
        print("Ice Punch is hyper effective!")
      }
      if(M== "Psystrike"){
        dmg<-damage(100)
        print("Psystrike has normal efficiency.")
      }
      if(M== "Aura Sphere"){
        dmg<-lowdamage(80)
      print("Aura Sphere is not very effective...")
      }
      if(M== "Solar Beam"){
      dmg<-lowdamage(100)
      print("Solar Beam is not very effective...")
      }
    hpRayquaza <- (hpRayquaza + dmg)
    print(paste("hpRayquaza:", hpRayquaza))
    }
    if(speedM<speedR){  
  for(a in c("Rayquaza is angry...", "Go!")){
      print(a)
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }
     if(R == "Outrage"){
      dmg<-damage(120)
      print("Outrage has normal efficiency.")
    }
     if(R == "Dragon Ascent"){
      dmg<-damage(120)
      print("Dragon Ascent has normal efficiency.")
    }
     if(R == "Crunch"){
      dmg<-highdamage(80)
      print("Crunch is super effective!")
      }
     if(R == "Brutal Swing"){
      dmg<-highdamage(60)
      print("Brutal swing is super effective!")
       }
    hpMewtwo <- (hpMewtwo + dmg)
    print(paste("hpMewtwo:",hpMewtwo))
    }
    res<-c(hpMewtwo,hpRayquaza)
  }
  
  return(res)
}

## Some values

hpMewtwo = 300
hpRayquaza = 600
speedM_v = 10
speedR_v = 8

## safe as a result
result_round1<-round1(hpRayquaza=hpRayquaza,hpMewtwo = hpMewtwo)
result_round1[1]
```

if you want to analyze the steps during a fight i would create a dataframe at the beginning of the round function with the columns `hp_pke1, hp_pke2, akk, dmg`